# What Salesforce Standard URLs for Configuring Web Server Flow Exist and how should I use there?

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

I am following this video on how to setup web server Oauth Flow:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cViU2-xVscA

One of the steps involved is setting up the Callback URL and the instructor inserts the below URL:

https://login.salesforce.com/oauth2/callback

Now my question is how the instructor found this URL? It also does not work. But where in the Salesforce documentation are there standard URLs for configuring the OAuth Web Server flow.

I also saw the following full URL:

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=https://login.salesforce.com/oauth2/callback&response_type=code

Are these standard URLs required for OAuth? How can I find this full list of URLs? My goal is to test out the connected App that I have just created and I am trying to figure out how to test this on my chrome browser. (Adding this additional context so that you can understand where I am trying to go with this)

Answer (score 2):

That specific callback URL is used for apps that don't need a callback (e.g. a WebView-based extension can just detect the URL at the end of the process). It simply returns a 200 status code upon successful login. If you need a callback URL, it should be a link to your app such that it can read the code and complete the login flow. The /token and /authorize endpoints are required for the complete flow experience. All of the URLs you'll need are in the documentation for the appropriate flow; there are several different kinds available depending on the use case. You can read all about it in [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5).